# Center a table of images on a webpage

Tags: html

I was wondering if anyone could help me regarding centering the table on this webpage:

http://stoltz.caltech.edu/members.html

Specifically, the table containing the photos of each person is off center from the header of the webpage. I've been trying to center it to no avail.

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I went to your website and did some changes in css now you can try these changes

```
body {
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  color: #231F20;
  font: normal 12px/2.4em Verdana, Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 -120px;
  padding: 0;
}
```